# PM2 App gets permission denied when printing

Tags: node.js, pm2, udev

I have a running pm2 application, the application's method for printing fails with EACCES: permission denied, open /dev/sopa_printer0
However if manually execute the application with node it prints without issues. The printer is /dev/sopa_printer0

From pm2 logs:

```
Print failed Print failed: Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/dev/sopa_printer0'
```

From the command line: node server.js
it prints correctly.

Any idea where I can start to debug?

```
node version 10.0.0
npm version 6.0.0
pm2 version 2.10.3
```

I  added my user to lp group with:

```
sudo adduser $USER lp

cat /etc/group | grep -i lp
lp:x:7:imagineing
```

imagineing is my user

```
$ ls -alh /dev/sopa_printer0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 May 26 12:35 /dev/sopa_printer0  -> usb/lp0
$ ls -alh /dev/usb/lp0
crw-rw---- 1 root lp 180, 0 May 26 12:35 /dev/usb/lp0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly I fixed my issue. I added 777 to the /dev/usb/lp0 device (I think others combinations will work but the app is now working)

```
$ ls -al sopa_printer0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 May 26 12:35 sopa_printer0 -> usb/lp0
$ ls -al usb/lp0
crwxrwxrwx 1 root lp 180, 0 May 26 12:35 usb/lp0
```